# Need to send a JSON post request with a very long string value

Tags: python, json, post, request, rundeck

I'm developing a ticketing bot for a really specific usage. I need to send a POST request to a Rundeck server, and in one of the data fields there's a (ofter very) long string of text from an e-mail's body.

This POST request is returning an error from Rundeck every time. I'm coding with Python and using the "requests" module for doing such requests.

**EXAMPLE OF THE POST REQUEST:**

```
data =  {"options":{
            "solicitant":"NAME.NAME.NAME",
            "emailSolicitant":"email@server.tld",
            "client":"CLIENT NAME",
            "subject":"Subject from the mail, this is working ok.",
            "body":"**HERE GOES THE LONG \n LONG \n LONG \n LONG BODY OF THE MESSAGE**",
          }
         }
```

**ERROR I'M GETTING FROM RUNDECK:**

```
File "/path/to/a/shell/script.sh", line 18
    body = 'HERE GOES THE LONG
                             ^
    SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
    Failed: NonZeroResultCode: Remote command failed with exit status 1
```

**HOW I'M MAKING THE POST REQUEST**

```
requestJob = requests.post('https://myrundeck.tld/api/31/job/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx/run', headers=headers, data=str(data))
```

IMO Looks like it's not accepting the "\n" as part of the text..

Comment: Why did you used `data=str(data)`?

Comment: Not doing it this way results in a good execution of the Rundeck job, but all fields are left in blank and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score -1):

Here:

```
requestJob = requests.post(
    'https://myrundeck.tld/api/31/job/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx/run',
    headers=headers, 
    data=str(data)
    )
```

The `str(data)` is your problem - `requests.post()` [expects a `dict` here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests), so just pass `data=data`.

Note that depending on your API specs you might have other errors further down the line.

Comment: Doing it this way results in a good execution of the Rundeck job, but all fields are left in blank. I can't figure out why.

Comment: @AlvaroM I can't either - and I'm not going to open a Rundeck account, read the doc etc to find out. But perhaps inspecting the response and checking the Rundesk API doc might help ? (just like reading ̀`python-requests` doc would have solved this first issue FWIW).

Comment: I already did read the python-requests doc, and I was doing it without the str() before. But it was not working, so I changed it. I am now reading Rundeck documentation rn. But it has no log about what has done/recieved and I can't see what is it doing. Thanks a lot for your time and your answers.

Comment: "I was doing it without the str() before. But it was not working, so I changed it" => programming by permutation never really work. A couple hints though: 1/ __check your response__ (status code and content) - any decent API will send you some feedback that way, and it should be documented -, and 2/ like most APIs, [Rundesk expects json or XML](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html#xml-and-json), not form-encoded data (how to send json with `requests` is of course documented).

Comment: "Thanks a lot for your time and your answers" => you're welcome ;-) Just note that the usual way to thanks someone here is to accept the answer (if it solved the issue of course) and possibly upvote it. Not that I care much personnally - a mere "thank you" is enough to make my day -, but other contributors might care more...